# for loop in R — generating and calculate different results

Tags: r, for-loop

Giving rnorm(100) I need to create a for loop in R to calculate the mean and the standard deviation generating 100 different numbers each time, and store those results in a vector.

How can I accomplish that?

so far

```
a <- rnorm(100) # generate 100 random numbers with normal distribution

sample <- 100 # number of samples
results <- rep(NA, 100) # vector creation for storing the results

for (i in 1:sample){
results[i] <- as.data.frame() # then i stuck here, lol, the most important part
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a homework question to me.

Answer (score 0):

This function will return the mean, standard deviation and sample size. The only argument required is the sample size (n).

```
results <- function(n) {

  data.frame(Mean = mean(rnorm(n)),
             Stdev = sd(rnorm(n)),
             n = n
             ) -> out

  return(out)

}
```